# Find file by -m not finding files modified within date

Tags: linux

I'm trying to find all files modified in the month of August.

```
[user@server:/path-to-file/pdfs/]$ ll
total 152
-rw-r--r-- 1 wwwrun www 105713 2012-08-28 12:05 file1.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 wwwrun www  49059 2012-08-28 12:05 file2.pdf
```

The modification date is last month on the 28th.  This command doesn't find these files and I'm unsure why.  I've never used `-mtime`.  Is the date and/or timestamp shown when I `ls` to view those PDFs not the modification time?

```
find "/path-to-file/pdfs/" -mtime -56 -mtime +31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your calculations again. Today is Sept 25 and your file was modified on Aug 28, which is about 28 days ago. In your command you are using `-mtime +31` (meaning modified more than 31 days ago) hence why it is not being found.

Try changing your command to:

```
find "/path-to-file/pdfs/" -mtime -56 -mtime +27
```

Comment: Ahh... gotcha.  I thought it was +31 days from -56 days ago.  So today is the 25th, if I wanted to find everything from last month I'd look for `... -mtime -56 -mtime +25`?

Comment: yes, it's all relative to today. So +25 means "25 days older than today".

Comment: How do minutes factor into this?  It seems like the longer this day goes on my numbers keep changing.  In truth, this is historical so it shouldn't be...